# Converting to RDD fails

Tags: scala, entity-framework, apache-spark

My code is as below. I read a CSV file which has two columns. Loop through the elements of the Dataframe by converting to a RDD. Now i wanted to create a DF of each Element. Below code fails. Can anyone please help.

```
    val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").load("c:\\file.csv") //CSV has 3 columns
     
    for (row <- df1.rdd.collect)
     {
       var tab1 =  row.mkString(",").split(",")(0) //Has Tablename
       var tab2 =  row.mkString(",").split(",")(1) //One Select Statment
       var tab3 =  row.mkString(",").split(",")(1) //Another Select Statment      
       
       val newdf = spark.createDataFrame(tab1).toDF("Col") // This is not working
               
     }
```

I want to join tab2 dataframe with tab3 and append tablename. For example

Exceution of query in tab2 and tab3 gives below result.

```
Col1     col2
---      ---
A         B
C         D
E         F
G         H
```

I want as below:

```
Col0  Col1  Col2
----  ----   ---
Tab1   A      B
Tab1   C      D
Tab2   E      F
Tab3   G      h
```

Now tab1 tab2 tab2.. etc this information is in CSV file file which am reading. I want to convert that col0 to a datafram,so that i can read in Spark Sql

Comment: Could you tell us why you want to create one dataframe per line of your CSV? And what's the error you obtain?

Comment: Am not making dataframe per row but want it per column wise. Actually each column of csv is having a Oracle query which i need to execute.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Here you loop over all the rows of your rdd, and create a dataframe for each of them. Your code probably does not work because `spark.createDataFrame` expects a sequence of tuples. Could you for instance provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: I am very sorry. What you are trying to do is still unclear for me. What is the content of the csv file?

Comment: I am creating a temp view from tab2 and tab3. Doingg a cross join. Now I want to do again cross join with tab1. How can i do that. Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my replacing below:

```
val newdf = spark.createDataFrame(tab1).toDF("Col") // This is not working
```

By

```
val newDf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(newdf)).toDF("Col")
```